# Variables defined in an #include'd makefile, are they visible to the includer?

Tags: makefile

The [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Include) is not explicit about whether variables from an `include`ed file are available in the file which `include`ed it. I am fairly certain the answer is no, but I wanted to test it.

I created the file `makefile`

```
#include file2.mk

all:
    @echo $(myvar)
```

and as expected, the output in the terminal was `echo` followed by an empty line. Then, I removed the `#`,
created `file2.mk`

```
myvar = "hello world"

all2: 
    echo $(myvar)
```

and ran `makefile`. If make does not remember variables from `#include`ed makefiles, I expect the output to be

```
hello world
echo
(\n)
```

and if it does remember, I expect the output to be

```
hello world
echo "hello world"
hello world.
```

However, the actual output is just
`hello world`

Comment: Of course the variables are available in the main makefile. That's even given as a reason to use an include file: **One occasion for using include directives is when several programs, handled by individual makefiles in various directories, need to use a common set of variable definitions**

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. I read that, and I thought for sure it does not mean what I think it means.

Comment: It should be noted that includes are not *quite* textual; multi-line things (rules and variable definitions, unless they are written using single-line syntax) must be within a single Makefile.

Comment: You seem to expect the `all2` recipe in the included makefile to be invoked.  But it will not be.  The only rules that will be run are those for the target `all` in the primary Makefile.

Comment: That's some next-level doublethink there, to think something does not mean what you think it means :)  I'm not sure why you expect the first `hello world` in your sample output.  Where is that coming from?  I would expect just `echo hello world` / `hello world`.

Comment: @WilliamPursell is not quite right.  Because the `include file2.mk` comes _before_ the definition of the `all:` target, the only target that will be run is the `all2` target not the `all` target.  It would be easier to see what's happening if you made your rules print something different (such as `$@` for example).  In make, unless you give a specific target on the command line only the first target will be built (and of course, anything needed to bring the first target up to date).

Comment: Actually, it will depend on the order.  If the include is before the `all` rule, then the `all2` rule will be executed.  Otherwise, the `all` rule.  But not both.

Comment: @MadScientist @MadScientist Haha If I've learned anything, it's that things in programming are not as they appear at first glance (for me). I think I understand now. I did not think that `include` statements are considered targets, since they don't have the syntax `text:`. But now I understand that they are targets, and this explains everything.

Comment: I also had the `@` in the wrong file in this question, so my predicted output doesn't make sense in any case.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks, i think I understand. `include ...` is considered a target as well, correct? If yes, I understand everything.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want include statements to be targets.  It's very simple: an include statement takes the text of the included file and pretends it appeared at that location in the including file.  So if you created a new makefile where you replaced each `include` statement with the complete contents of the included file, then told make to use that combined makefile, you'd get the same behavior as using the `include` statement.  It works exactly the same as C/C++ `#include` preprocessor statements, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: @MadScientist Ahh okay everything makes sense now, thanks!